# jQuery: Append browser window dimensions to href

Tags: jquery

I am wanting to use jQuery to add the current browser window dimensions to the end of the `href` of certain `a` tags.

The specific `a` tags all have their `href` begin with `secondary_imgs.php` but other than that, differ by containing data, i.e. `secondary_imgs.php?Id=x&Title=y`. I could easily set all these tags to have a specific class if that helps the problem.

I think the best approach to this would be to append the `&width=x&height=y` to the end of the `href` on document ready, and then set a second function to replace those values, whenever the page is resized.

Alas, I am at a loss as to how to complete this. I have the constituent parts (I think), but need help combining them in the proper way.

**Here's what I have thus far:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();
    $("a[href^='secondary_imgs.php']").attr('href', function() {
        return this.append('&w=width&h=height') 
    });
});
```

I tried to specify just the `a` tags who's `href` *begins* with `secondary_imgs.php`. I think that would be the best way of specifying it. But beyond that, I don't know where I'm making a mistake.

For the second half of this, where the values are replaced when the window is resized, I thought using `.resize()` would be the best to trigger the function, however I don't know how to set it up to *replace* the values, not add to them.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the loop `this` refers to a DOM element, so you can't use the `append` method on it. Besides, the append method adds elements inside an element, it doesn't concatenate strings.

To put the values of the `width` and `height` variables in the string you have to concatentate them into a string. Putting the variable names inside a string won't evaluate them.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var width = $(window).width();
  var height = $(window).height();
  $("a[href^='secondary_imgs.php']").attr('href', function(index, attr) {
    return attr + '&w=' + width + '&h=' + height; 
  });
});
```

If you want to get the window size at the moment that the user clicks on the link instead of the size when the page loads, then you would rather catch the click event, create a new URL and apply it yourself instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("a[href^='secondary_imgs.php']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the click
    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();
    var url = $(this).attr('href') + '&w=' + width + '&h=' + height;
    window.location.href = url; // replace the link action
  });
});
```

#### Edit:

To be compatible with other scripts that take over the link action, you would make sure that you bind your event before loading/activating that script, and only change the URL and write it back, but first checking if there are properties that needs to be removed:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("a[href^='secondary_imgs.php']").click(function(e){
    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var idx = url.indexOf('&w=');
    if (idx != -1) {
      url = url.substr(0, idx);
    }
    url += '&w=' + width + '&h=' + height;
    $(this).attr('href', url);
  });
});
```

Comment: Awesome. This looks perfect. However, as you mentioned in a comment, I need the values to be replaced if the link is clicked successive times. Will this take care of that?

Comment: @stefmikhail: Yes, the second alternative will create the URL with the window size at the moment the link is clicked. As the URL is not saved back in the link, there is nothing that needs to be replaced.

Comment: It's working like a charm. Thanks very much. However, it would seem some other attributes in the `a` tag are not. In particular, the `target='_blank'` isn't working. As well, there is another piece of functionality associated with the links by having `class='gallery'` in the `a` tag. It would seem this functionality is also not working now. Could it be that the above method is somehow messing with this? I also have another question for you. Perhaps a quick chat if you have the time?

Comment: After thinking about it a bit, I realized why there was this problem. Namely that because the javascript was redirecting the page itself, the normal function included in the `a` tag wasn't kicking in. I think I'm going to have to use your first example, where it populates the URL on page load. I will have to add the `resize` function as well unfortunately. Any thoughts?

Comment: You could support the target attribute by using `window.open(url,target)`, but any other functionality that you apply to the link would of course not be supported. You can still add the size at the time of the click, so that you avoid using the `resize` event, as that just makes your page more sluggish. Just add the size to the URL, store it back and let the click even continue as normal, but before adding the size you have to check if there already are size properties that you have to remove first.

Comment: This problem has gotten much more complicated than I originally thought it would. I'm not sure if you are familiar with *shadowbox.js* but I'm using it to open the `secondary_imgs.php`, the page where I am trying to send the dimensions. For some reason, with shadowbox disabled, it works, but with it enabled, it doesn't. The really strange part is the data already present in the URL (`imgId, imgTitle`) are making it through no problem. I can't understand why the first two data sets in the URL are sent, but the last two (`width & height`) are not. Any ideas?

Comment: could this be done with Ajax? do you think it would make it through then? And btw, all `shadowbox.js` does, is open external files (images or html or php) in a frame on top of the current window. Very clean for the image gallery I am building.

Comment: The reason that the data doesn't make it through is likely because the shadowbox takes over the event, just like in my second example, so your event handler runs when the URL has already been used to open the frame. You would have to make sure that your event is bound before the shadowbox binds its events, so that you can update the URL before the shadowbox uses it.

Comment: Just as you were writing you comment I remembered that shadowbox has some ajax solutions built in. I'm going to explore those as well as your suggestion. My question is, as your second example (where the window dimensions are queried on the click event) does not allow for the class `gallery` to be used, I'm wondering if it would be possible to still query the dimensions at the time of the click, but maintain the original click function instead of using `window.location.href`?

Comment: Got it to work. I feel stupid considering all I had to do was switch the order so that the `shadowbox` function was after the one you wrote. Again though, I really do need to query the dimensions at the moment the link is clicked. If the user changes their window size, it will seriously affect what I'm doing.

Comment: I added an alternative that sets the size parameter when the link is clicked, and removes previous size parameters.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to be working again. I made sure to place the shadowbox function *after* the new one you provided for me, and like I said, with the first example you provided, this seemed to do the trick. Don't know why this isn't working in this case however. Could it have something to do with the addition of the dimensions to the URL coming *after* shadowbox is being called? I'm not saying that is what the problem is, I just don't know why one would work, and now this one not work.

Comment: It's possible that the shadowbox code picks up the URL when it adds the event handlers to the element, in that case it's not possible to add anything to the URL at the time of the click. You would have to investigate if you can integrate your code with the shadowbox code to provide it with the URL.

Comment: So it looks like I found a solution. There are two pieces of code that shadowbox offers: `Shadowbox.clearCache();` to clear Shadowbox's cache `Shadowbox.setup();` to set up all Shadowbox links. Does that make sense to you? I used your last example and placed both functions at the end, after `$(this).attr('href', url);`. One question, I noticed you left the `e` in `.click(function(e)`. Am I right to assume that this was just an oversight on your part, and carried over from the second example?

Answer (score 2):

Can I suggest a different approach?

If you wait until someone clicks on the link, then you only have to do the calculation once and can forget about the resize. Simply bind to the link's click event:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("a[href^='secondary_imgs.php']").bind({
      'click'  :  function(e) {
        var w = $(window).width();
        var h = $(window).height();
        $(this).attr('href', function() {
          return this.append('&w='+w+'&h='+h) ;
        });
      }
    }) ;
  });
})(jQuery) ;
```

N.B. - you will still need to ensure that your href contains a '?' before using '& as the first appended character.

Comment: that was actually my first approach, but I was concerned that the data wouldn't be appended in time before the link fired. You think it'll be fine? And yes, there will already be two sets of data, so only an & is needed at the beginning. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: This is exactly right... except the code within .append() will append the string '&w=width&h=height'. Should be '&w='+width+'&h='+height+'. I'ad also be careful about using 'width' and 'height' as variable names. Haven't tested it, but those names could give you problems in IE.

Comment: @maxedison - thanks, fixed. stefmikhail - yes, all the bound events will be fired before the link is processed normally by the browser. The only time you will run into issues is if you have bound another function to the click and are doing ajax loads following the href attribute. Then you will need to deal with ordering issues.

Comment: Doing it in the click event means that the link only works properly once. If you click it again, the event handler will add the values once more.

Comment: @Guffa. This is true, so some code should be added to remove the w & h parameters if the user clicks the link multiple times before the page refreshes. However, this is still the correct approach because it is more efficient than binding to the resizing of the window.

Comment: @Guffa - What would you suggest is added if the link is clicked more than once (which it very well might be). I need those values to be replaced for sure!

Comment: @stefmikhail: If you add the size each time the link is clicked, you end up with something like `...&w=1280&h=960&w=1280&h=960&w=1280&h=960&w=1280&h=960`. I just added an alternative in my answer, where you add the size to the URL but don't put the URL back in the link.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
this.append('&w=width&h=height')
```

Try

```
$(this).attr('href', function(i, val) {
      return val + '&w=width&h=height';
});
```